# How to create loadbalancer in openstack for kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, openstack

I want to create VMs in openstack and install kubernetes on them and use openstack loadbalancer in kubernetes.But i do not know how to communicate with openstack.I ask it in ask.openstack.org but no one can answer that so i ask it here.

Comment: There is a lot of documentation available, e.g. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/#openstack and https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-openstack/tree/master/docs

Comment: How can i configure openstack?should install sth in openstack?

Comment: You need to create cloud.conf on each Kubernetes master node and add --cloud-provider openstack and --cloud-config /path/to/cloud.conf arguments to kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager and kubelet. Read more here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/

Comment: it is kubernetes config but what should i do on my openstack?

Comment: Ideally nothing.

Comment: do you use openstak loadbalancer by kubernetes?